# Tile grout lines?

Tags: grout, tiling

I have laid some new tiles in my hallway and they are a larger tile with what looks like a grout recess to make them look like 4 smaller tiles. My question is, are those lines meant to be grouted or should they me left ungrouted and just grout the main grout lines between the large tiles. The ‘built in’ grout lines are roughly 2mm wide but only 2mm deep. Is that enough to hold the grout in over time?

Many thanks in advance[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

2mm wide and 2mm deep will not hold grout. It won't even survive the tile grout sponge cleanup. When you do your grouting just for the main tiles, try to match the depth of the built in grout lines. Pictures are always nice on posts like this.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, currently in the process of grouting and it definitely looks better with grout in the recess but I have been cleaning it out again as I go along. Don’t know how to add a picture or I would do.

Comment: Ah ok, I’ve added a picture to the original post.....

Comment: The horizontal line is the main grout line and the vertical line is the tile recess.

Comment: Also, upon further investigation, the recess appears to be unglazed.

Comment: @OliverGriffiths Is there a reason you went with the gray grout instead of white, which would have matched the "built in" lines?  Most grouts are un glazed so they'd want the recessed grout to match the finish of the regular grout.